# python pandas reading a timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to read a date-time in microsecond format.

```
1500909283.955000
```

The expected output should be something like

```
July 24, 2017 3:14:43.955 PM
```

But when I use pandas to_datetime function I got

```
1970-01-01 00:00:01.500909283
```

I tried all possible format with no success.

Any hints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `unit='s'` param for [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime):

```
In[4]:
pd.to_datetime(1500909283.955000, unit='s')

Out[4]: Timestamp('2017-07-24 15:14:43.955000')
```

the timestamp is seconds since the epoch

The default `unit` value is nanoseconds:

```
In[5]:
pd.to_datetime(1500909283.955000, unit='ns')

Out[5]: Timestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:01.500909283')
```

which is what you observed

Answer (score 2):

Need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `unit`, data are in `seconds`, not in `milisecond`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['1500909283.955000','1500909283.955000']})
df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'], unit='s')
print (df)
                      col
0 2017-07-24 15:14:43.955
1 2017-07-24 15:14:43.955
```

For `milliseconds`:

```
df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'], unit='ms')
print (df)
                         col
0 1970-01-18 08:55:09.283955
1 1970-01-18 08:55:09.283955
```

If need another format use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['col1'] = df['col'].dt.strftime('%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S.%f %p')
print (df)
                      col                             col1
0 2017-07-24 15:14:43.955  Jul 24, 2017 03:14:43.955000 PM
1 2017-07-24 15:14:43.955  Jul 24, 2017 03:14:43.955000 PM
```